# Container is unhealthy. Encountered errors while bringing up the project

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana

Upgraded Elasticsearch from 7.10.1 to 7.17.6 by changing the version number in .env files.
environment is a 3 node cluster (es01, es02, es03) on the same server and 1 kibana kib01 on it.

Running the `sudo docker-compose up -d` gives below error. Unhealthy container as mentioned in error is es01.

```
Starting es03   ... done
Recreating es01 ... done
Starting es02   ... done

ERROR: for kib01  Container "<container-ID>" is unhealthy.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

var/log/messages file shows below if it's related to the issue

```
Sep  9   avahi-daemon[890]: Withdrawing address record for  on <ID1>.
Sep  9   avahi-daemon[890]: Withdrawing workstation service for <id>.
Sep  9   libvirtd: 2022-09-09 : 1468: error : virFileReadAll:1460 : Failed to open file '/sys/class/net/<id>/operstate': No such file or directory
Sep  9   libvirtd: 2022-09-09 : 1468: error : virNetDevGetLinkInfo:2552 : unable to read: /sys/class/net/<id>/operstate: No such file or directory
Sep  9   kernel: device <ID1> left promiscuous mode
Sep  9   kernel: : port 2(<ID1>) entered disabled state
Sep  9   avahi-daemon[890]: Withdrawing workstation service for <ID1>.
Sep  9   NetworkManager[884]: <info>  [] manager: (<ID2>): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/100)
Sep  9   NetworkManager[884]: <info>  [] device (<ID1>): released from master device 
Sep  9   kernel: : port 3() entered disabled state
```

...................................................................
Update:
There is another folder at the same location. when i remove the previous containers created and try to run the sudo docker-compose up -d from this folder. Gets below output and elasticsearch cluster health shows good for all 3 nodes but going to the **Kibana Home frontend url still throws 'site can't be reached error. ANy help to resolve this issue.**

```
Creating es02 ... done
Creating es03 ... done
Creating es01 ... done
Creating kib01 ... done
```